# android - sms type constants

Tags: android, sms

Where can I find the API to find out what the "**type**" constants are for SMS?

I'm getting the values: 1, 6 and 2.

But don't know which one is outgoing, incoming, etc...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to `TextBasedSmsColumns` the mapping is following:

```
MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL    = 0;
MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX  = 1;
MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT   = 2;
MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT  = 3;
MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX = 4;
MESSAGE_TYPE_FAILED = 5; // for failed outgoing messages
MESSAGE_TYPE_QUEUED = 6; // for messages to send later
```

Comment: What are draft and outbox? All message type in 3 devices are indox or sent.

Comment: Draft: if somebody didn't spend any message but typed it in the box, Outbox : it has started sending the sms but haven't been sent yet